# Git branch unknown to local clone

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I have a git repository with two branches. If I clone my repo I can only see the master branch. I have both branches up to date. The problem is I don't fully understand merging and branching. Darn it!

My example can be seen here:

http://github.com/rimian/rimian/network

Can anyone tell me how to get this back to normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have both branches in your cloned repository, but they are called `origin/master` and `origin/ui`. By default, it will also have created a local branch called `master` that tracks `origin/master`, and this is what you see when you do `git branch` for example. You can see all remote branches with the command `git branch -r`. You can create a new local branch that tracks the remote one, and switch to it, for example with `git checkout -tb ui origin/ui`.

Answer (score 1):

When I run

```
git clone http://github.com/rimian/rimian.git
cd rimian
gitk --all & # You can also use git branch -a if gitk is not installed
```

gitk shows me an ui branch and a master branch. I could for instance run

```
git merge origin/ui
git push
```

To get the contents of the  ui branch into master and update master on github.

Please note that I did not use the url you posted when cloning. I recommend you read [this github guide on branching/merging](http://learn.github.com/p/branching.html)